# How can I make a fast pixel-changing animation widget in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation

### What I want:

I want an animation widget with fast display<sup>1</sup> generation (meaning the generation time should be smaller than 20 seconds) and with a special function to run pixel-changing animations **with a very small run time (meaning the run time should be smaller than 20 ms)** in Python 3.

### Wrong method:

The simplest method is a pixel panel. But it is generating very slowly<sup>2</sup>.

This is the code:

```py
import tkinter as t

tk = t.Tk()
n = 1100
k = 900 # Display sizes
canvas = t.Canvas(tk, width =k, height = n)
canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
ids = [] # Pixel identifiers

for i in range(n):
    id2 = []
    for j in range(k):
        id2.append(cv.create_rectangle(i,j,i+1,j+1,outline = "black"))
    ids.append(id2)

def animation(animation_list): # Animation function, animation_list - list of coordinates and colors tuples (as an example,[(1, 0, "red"), (2, 1, "green")].
    global canvas
    for x, y, color in animation_list:
        canvas.itemconfig(ids[x][y],outline = color)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Sizes are 1100x900 pixels (990k pixels)
<sup>2</sup> Debug (not debugger) shows 22 seconds, but it took more than a minute, and the window is lagging.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419940/why-arent-people-undoing-downvotes-even-when-the-author-fixes-all-problems) (likely to be automatically deleted within a few weeks - would then only be visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it! Thanks to [Mike-SMT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7475225/mike-smt) for the idea!

This is my code:

```py
import os
import pygame as pg
from random import *
# It is used as a library

main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
data_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, "data")


def show(image): # Shows surface
    screen = pg.display.get_surface()
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
    pg.display.flip()


def main(): # Reacts on window closing.
    pg.init()

    pg.display.set_mode((255, 255))
    surface = pg.Surface((255, 255))

    pg.display.flip()
    while 1:
        for ev in pg.event.get():
            if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
                brk = 0
                pg.display.quit()
def animate(pixels): # Animation function.pixels is array of arrays as [x, y, (r,g,b)]
    global surface
    ar = pg.PixelArray(surface)
    for x, y, color in pixels:
        ar[x, y] = color
    del ar
    show(surface)
main()
```

---

It solves the problem, because it is fast and has an animation function, as needed.